# Shifted edge labels in tikzpictures in nodes side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, labels, edge

I'm trying to make two graphs and place them side by side and place edge labels over edges in the two graphs (as can be seen in the picture), but I am not successful in the second graph. My approach is to create two nodes in one `tikzpicture` nad place another two `tikzpicture`s (the graphs itself) in these nodes. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing, snakes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=white],
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, fill=orange]
        \node(graph) at (0,1) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, thick]
            \begin{scope}
                \node[vertex] (root)    at (4,  5) {};
                \node[vertex] (o)       at (4,  4) {};
                \node[vertex] (oc)      at (4,  3) {};
                \node[vertex] (a)       at (5,  4) {};

                \foreach \xfrom/\xto/\xlabel in {
                    root/o/o, o/oc/c,
                    root/a/a} {
                    \draw (\xfrom) to node[pos=0.5]{\xlabel} (\xto);
                };
            \end{scope}             
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };

        \node[right = of graph] (graph2) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, thick]
            \begin{scope}
                \node[vertex] (root)    at (4,  5) {};          
                \node[vertex] (o)       at (4,  4) {};
                \node[vertex] (oc)      at (4,  3) {};          
                \node[vertex] (a)       at (5,  4) {};

                \foreach \xfrom/\xto/\xlabel in {
                    root/o/o, o/oc/c} 
                {
                    \draw (\xfrom) to node[pos=0.5]{\xlabel} (\xto);
                };
                \foreach \xfrom/\xto/\xlabel in {
                    root/a/a} 
                {
                    \draw (\xfrom) to node[midway]{\xlabel} (\xto);
                };
            \end{scope}             
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My result is as follows:
[image]

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I would appreciate any suggestions. (I need to do it this way because of exact positioning of the graphs and because of additional arrows that will connect these graphs.)

EDIT:
Actually, I need to make an arrow between the two graphs:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing, snakes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=white],
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, fill=orange]
        \node(graph) at (0,1) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, thick]
            \begin{scope}
                \node[vertex] (root)    at (4,  5) {};
                \node[vertex] (o)       at (4,  4) {};
                \node[vertex] (oc)      at (4,  3) {};
                \node[vertex] (a)       at (5,  4) {};

                \foreach \xfrom/\xto/\xlabel in {
                    root/o/o, o/oc/c,
                    root/a/a} {
                    \draw (\xfrom) to node[pos=0.5]{\xlabel} (\xto);
                };
            \end{scope}             
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };

        \node[right = of graph] (graph2) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize, thick]
            \begin{scope}
                \node[vertex] (root)    at (4,  5) {};          
                \node[vertex] (o)       at (4,  4) {};
                \node[vertex] (oc)      at (4,  3) {};          
                \node[vertex] (a)       at (5,  4) {};

                \foreach \xfrom/\xto/\xlabel in {
                    root/o/o, o/oc/c} 
                {
                    \draw (\xfrom) to node[pos=0.5]{\xlabel} (\xto);
                };
                \foreach \xfrom/\xto/\xlabel in {
                    root/a/a} 
                {
                    \draw (\xfrom) to node[midway]{\xlabel} (\xto);
                };
            \end{scope}             
            \end{tikzpicture}
        };  

        \begin{scope}[segment amplitude=4]
        \draw[snake=triangles] (graph) -- (graph2);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
I'm not sure if this is possible with `pic`...

Comment: You should not nest `tikzpicture` environments.

Comment: OK, so my approach is completely wrong? There is no way how to make my example working?

Comment: There is the `pic` syntax, but since this is too long for a comment I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `pic` syntax allowing one to draw small pictures in a `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows,decorations.pathreplacing, snakes}
%
    \tikzset{every node/.style={circle, minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, fill=white},
    vertex/.style={circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, fill=orange}}

\tikzset{
  mygraph/.pic={\begin{scope}[font=\footnotesize, thick]
                \node[vertex] (root)    at (4,  5) {};
                \node[vertex] (o)       at (4,  4) {};
                \node[vertex] (oc)      at (4,  3) {};
                \node[vertex] (a)       at (5,  4) {};

                \foreach \xfrom/\xto/\xlabel in {
                    root/o/o, o/oc/c,
                    root/a/a} {
                    \draw (\xfrom) to node[pos=0.5]{\xlabel} (\xto);
                };
                \end{scope}
  }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic (graph) {mygraph};
    \pic at (3,0) (graph2) {mygraph};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to change some things, then you can work with parameters. (And please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.)

**EDIT**: To reference the nodes inside the `pic`s outside, you just need to add the appropriate prefix, e.g.

```
\draw[-latex,shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm] (grapha) -- (graph2o);
```

will yield

[image]

**Explanation**: the nodes inside the picture can be referenced as `<pic name><node name>` such that the node `a` in the pic named `graph` becomes grapha. (`shorten` just shortens the arrow.) Notice that you could also play with nodes and the path picture key, but for this this might be less elegant.

Comment: So instead of nested `tikzpictures` I only add some `pic`s... Nice solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: And regarging the note about `tikzstyle` - I am a very occasional user of LaTeX, so I'm not very familiar about `tikzset`. So thank you also for information and warning.

Comment: Is there a way to name the two `pic`s to be able to draw an arrow between them?

Comment: @Frimlik Sure, just do `\draw[-latex,shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm] (grapha) -- (graph2o);`. Explanation: the nodes inside the picture can be referenced as `<pic name><node name>` such that the node `a` in the pic named `graph` becomes `grapha`. (`shorten` just shortens the arrow.) Notice that you could also play with nodes and the `path picture` key, but for this this might be less elegant.

Comment: I edited question - I need the arrow to be directed from center of the left and to the center of the right graph.

Comment: @Frimlik `\path (grapha) -- (graph2o) coordinate[pos=0.2] (start)
 coordinate[pos=0.8] (end); 
 \draw[snake=triangles,segment amplitude=4] (start) to (end);`. Notice that I am not supposed to be doing this. Rather, you are supposed to ask a new question.